# Laravel - Fortify guard for different routes and unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, fortify, guard

I am currently developing unit test for my routes and I ran into an weird situation.

I have some routes that I created in the routes/fortify.php file.

Some one those routes use another fortify.guard (admin and user doesn't have access to the same pages).

In order to do that, I wrote this in the FortifyServiceProvider class :

```php
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        Fortify::ignoreRoutes();
        if(request()->is('api/v1/admin/*')){
            config()->set('fortify.guard', 'admin');
        }
    }
```

Now, when I run `php artisan test` it doesn't work anymore, since the `request()`'s route is GET / (that, I do not know why.)

See the code of my test below :

```php
    public function loginAsTestAdmin(): void
    {
        $payload = ['email' => 'admin@example.com', 'password' => bcrypt('password')];
        $this->post('api/v1/admin/login', $payload)->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

When calling this route, the `if(request()->is('api/v1/admin/*'))` test fail and therefore, the guard attempt to retrieve the model User instead of the model Admin in the database and ends up with authentication failure (since the user with email 'admin@example.com' does not exist).

So, I figured out that dynamically changing the config to set the correct guard is probably not the Laravel way of doing this.

How should I declare my routes so they use the correct guard ?

Comment: I would advise against using `request()` in service providers. There's no guarantee that a service provider is registered or even is booted after the request is initiated (even if it currently is, this is not guaranteed to be in the future and if you switch to using e.g. Octane service providers are registered and booted once and not on every request)

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, exactly. I want to stop using that request thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this in config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

and in routes/fortify.php:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:admin'])->group(function () {
    // routes protected by the admin guard, for example
    Route::post('api/v1/admin/login', [\App\Http\Controllers\AdminLoginController::class, 'login']);
});

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    // routes protected by the default guard or user guard
});
```

This way you don't have to change the guard dynamically, you just specify the guard for each route, or a group of routes.

This is how you authenticate using the 'admin' guard

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials);
```

This is how you can access the authenticated user so you can use the object or user data:

```
$user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
```

And don't forget the use:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Comment: Absolute life saver, thank you my dude.
I will try this out and validate the answer if it works.
EDIT:
How you you specify the guard inside AdminLoginController ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you can check out the edit for he auth usage inside of the controller. Hopefully it will work :D